# How to refresh autolayout with another interface build in storyboard

Tags: storyboard, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to do view animation by designing two distinct interfaces in the storyboard. When an event triggers, it will change the autolayout constraints (or frames) as the destination layout.

**Is there any library to do this job? If no, please read on the following.**

Using autolayout to do view animation is an easy job. For example:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    self.heightConstraint.constant = 200
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

But if you want to change the whole layout by resetting all constraints of all subviews, it's not easy by programming. Using Interface Builder is the better choice to build a totally different layout with the same view objects. Because,

1. Interface Builder will check the constraint conflicts for you before running the app.
2. It's "what you see is what you get (WYSIWYG)."

Here is my idea:

1. Design a layout of the view of the controller in the Interface Builder (the original layout). View objects in the view can be fetched by `keypath` or `viewTag`.
2. Duplicate the view controller in the Interface Builder as destination layout, change all the frames and constraints as needed.
3. At runtime, when an event triggers the layout animation, it instantiates the view controller of the destination layout. Then, it replaces the constraints of the presenting view objects with the constraints of the view objects from the destination layout (through `keypath` or `viewTag`).

Here is my code:

```
// 1. Add the keypath `view` for the viewController. Use NSSet to remove duplicated keypaths or view tags.
NSSet *keySet = [NSSet setWithArray:[keypaths arrayByAddingObject:@"view"]];


// 2. Build the dictionaries to fetch corresponding view objects in the source and destination view controllers (presenting view and template view) by a specific key (a keypath or a view tag).
NSMutableDictionary *presentingViewsForKeypaths = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[keypaths count]];
NSMutableDictionary *templateViewsForKeypaths = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[keypaths count]];

[keySet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, BOOL *stop) {

    UIView *presentingViewForKeypath = nil;
    UIView *templateViewForKeypath = nil;

    // Fetch the view objects by the keypath or view tag.
    if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        presentingViewForKeypath = [self valueForKeyPath:key];
        templateViewForKeypath = [viewController valueForKeyPath:key];

    } else if ([key isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        presentingViewForKeypath = [self.view viewWithTag:[key integerValue]];
        templateViewForKeypath = [viewController.view viewWithTag:[key integerValue]];

    } else {
        NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"keypath (%@) is not kind of NSString or NSNumber.", key];
        NSAssert(nil, errorMessage);
        NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // The view objects should be found in both view controllers.
    if (!presentingViewForKeypath || !templateViewForKeypath) {
        NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KeynoteAnimation warning: keypath (%@) is not found.", key];
        NSAssert(nil, errorMessage);
        NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
        return;
    } else if (!templateViewForKeypath) {
        NSString *errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"KeynoteAnimation warning: keypath (%@) is not found.", key];
        NSAssert(nil, errorMessage);
        NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Add the view objects to the corresponding dictionaries.
    presentingViewsForKeypaths[key] = presentingViewForKeypath;
    templateViewsForKeypaths[key] = templateViewForKeypath;
}];


// 3. Change the constraints of the view objects for the keys.
NSSet *presentingViewsForKeypathsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[presentingViewsForKeypaths allValues]];
NSSet *templateViewsForKeypathsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:[templateViewsForKeypaths allValues]];
NSMutableArray *keysShouldUpdateItsViewFrame = [NSMutableArray array];

[keySet enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, BOOL *stop) {

    NSLog(@"========= Remove constraints for Key: %@ ==========", key);

    __block BOOL didChangeAnyConstraint = NO;

    UIView *presentingView = presentingViewsForKeypaths[key];
    UIView *templateView = templateViewsForKeypaths[key];

    // Remove the original constraints for the view objects.
    [presentingView.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([presentingViewsForKeypathsSet containsObject:constraint.firstItem] &&
            ([presentingViewsForKeypathsSet containsObject:constraint.secondItem] || !constraint.secondItem)) {

            NSLog(@"detect constraint: %@\nFind: %@ (%x) -- %@ (%x)", constraint,  NSStringFromClass([constraint.firstItem class]), [constraint.firstItem hash], NSStringFromClass([constraint.secondItem class]), [constraint.secondItem hash]);

            [presentingView removeConstraint:constraint];

            didChangeAnyConstraint = YES;
        }

    }];

    NSLog(@"----------- Add constraints for Key: %@ -----------", key);

    // Add the new constraints for the view objects.
    [templateView.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if ([templateViewsForKeypathsSet containsObject:constraint.firstItem] &&
            ([templateViewsForKeypathsSet containsObject:constraint.secondItem] || !constraint.secondItem)) {
            NSLog(@"detect constraint: %@\nFind: %@ (%x) -- %@ (%x)", constraint, NSStringFromClass([constraint.firstItem class]), [constraint.firstItem hash], NSStringFromClass([constraint.secondItem class]), [constraint.secondItem hash]);

            if ([constraint isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint")]) {
                NSLog(@"|||||||||||||||||||| WARNING ||||||||||||||||");
                //return; // Return here to filter out this constraint.
            }

            // Create the new NSLayoutConstraint for the presenting view object.
            NSArray *firstItemKeys = [templateViewsForKeypaths allKeysForObject:constraint.firstItem];
            NSArray *secondItemKeys = [templateViewsForKeypaths allKeysForObject:constraint.secondItem];

            id firstItemKey = [firstItemKeys count]? firstItemKeys[0]:nil;
            id secondItemKey = [secondItemKeys count]? secondItemKeys[0]:nil;

            id firstItem = firstItemKey? presentingViewsForKeypaths[firstItemKey]:nil;
            id secondItem = secondItemKey? presentingViewsForKeypaths[secondItemKey]:nil;

            NSLog(@"params for new constraints: %@:%@(%x) => %@:%@(%x) for view: %@(%x)", firstItemKey, NSStringFromClass([firstItem class]), [firstItem hash], secondItemKey, NSStringFromClass([secondItem class]), [secondItem hash], NSStringFromClass([presentingView class]), [presentingView hash]);

            NSLayoutConstraint *newLayoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstItem attribute:constraint.firstAttribute relatedBy:constraint.relation toItem:secondItem attribute:constraint.secondAttribute multiplier:constraint.multiplier constant:constraint.constant];

            [presentingView addConstraint:newLayoutConstraint];

            didChangeAnyConstraint = YES;
        }

    }];

    // Record the view object which doesn't have any layout constraint. It may change its frame set in the storyboard.
    if (!didChangeAnyConstraint) {
        [keysShouldUpdateItsViewFrame addObject:key];
    }       
}];


// Start Animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:1 initialSpringVelocity:1 options:0 animations:^{

    // Update the frame of the view objects which did not change its constraints (no constraint).
    [keysShouldUpdateItsViewFrame enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        UIView *presentingView = presentingViewsForKeypaths[key];
        UIView *templateView = templateViewsForKeypaths[key];

        presentingView.frame = templateView.frame;

    }];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"finish.");
}];
```

When adding the new constraints, if the class of the constraint is `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint`, it will crash and show the message: **When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.**

I think the view objects are already in the view hierarchy. I don't have no idea how to resolve with this issue.

If filtering out those constraints, it will not update the layout, and I'm not sure the constraints are satisfied.